# Using a custom float in beamer frame

Tags: beamer, newfloat

I have created a float with the [newfloat package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/newfloat.pdf) for graphs and plots. This way, I can use a different caption label and counter from the Figure floating environnement :

Graph 1 - Tresca stress vs Frequency
instead of
Figure 1 - Tresca stress vs Frequency

And it works pretty fine in an article document class.

The thing is, I'm working on a beamer presentation in which I want to use my custom floating envrionnement. However, it doesn't seem to work within

```
\begin{frame}
[...]
\end{frame}
```

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,name=Graphe]{graph}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}
    \begin{graph}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [
            height=5cm,
            width=10cm,
            grid=major,
            grid style={thin},
            xlabel=Fréquence (Hz),
            ylabel=Contrainte de Tresca (MPa),
            xmin=25,
            ymin=0,
            xmax=55,
            ymax=100
            ]
            \addplot [mark=*,line width=1pt]
            table [x=f, y=t, col sep=space] {TrescaVsFrequency.csv};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Contrainte maximale de Tresca calculée en fonction de la fréquence \label{TrescaVsFreq}}
    \end{graph}
%\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I uncomment

```
%\begin{frame}
```

and

```
%\end{frame}
```

The graph is not displayed, and I get an awful

"LaTeX error: Not in outer par mode.
Undefined control sequence
Missing Number, treated as zero"

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `beamer` disables floating for floats: I'm not sure if other packages allow for this. As the manual explains, they are likely inappropriate in a presentation ...

Answer (score 1):

You could define an ordinary new environment that changes the behaviour of the caption. Probably there are cleaner ways to implement this, but a quick hack could be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,name=Graphe]{graph}

\newenvironment{graph}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}{%
      \raggedright
      {%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}%
        \usebeamerfont*{caption name}%
        Graph%
        \usebeamertemplate{caption label separator}%
      }%
      \insertcaption\par
    }
    \begin{figure}%
}{%
    \end{figure}%
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{graph}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \path[fill=red] (90,100) ellipse (1.4cm and 1.75cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Contrainte maximale de Tresca calculée en fonction de la fréquence \label{TrescaVsFreq}}
    \end{graph}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]